# Multiply the rows of a matrix to get a vector: J, j701

Tags: vector, matrix, multiplication, j

I am programming with J.
I have this vector:

```
    F =: 5>\i.10
    F
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

How can I have this vector as result:

```
   (*/ 0 1 2 3 4), (*/ 1 2 3 4 5), (*/ 2 3 4 5 6), (*/ 3 4 5 6 7), (*/ 4 5 6 7 8), (*/ 5 6 7 8 9)
0 120 720 2520 6720 15120
   NB. I want to multiply all the rows
```

I tried:

```
   */ F
0 720 5040 20160 60480
```

but, how you can see it multiply the columns, and I want the rows.
How can I use the */ to multiply the rows? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, what you want is `5 */\ i.10`

```
   5 */\ i.10
0 120 720 2520 6720 15120
```

However, if you ever run across this issue in another context, and you really want to address the rows, you could say:

```
   ]M=:5>\i. 10
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9

   */ rows M
0 120 720 2520 6720 15120
```

Rows is defined by the standard library as `"1`. That is, it applies the verb at "rank 1".  Rank is a fundamental concept in J, and you'll need to understand it to progress with the language.

Comment: If you're comfortable with C or C-derived languages (like Java), you'll get a lot of insight out of "J for C Programmers", which is available in the J installation (under Help) and also on the web at: http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/contents.htm